# Could New York build a new mega airport?

Tags: airport, airport-design

Both New York and London have insufficient air traffic capacity. One option for London is to build a [new mega airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thames_Estuary_Airport) to replace [LHR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London_Heathrow_Airport). However, this option is not discussed much in NY. Would it be feasible to build a new mega airport to serve New York?

Answer (score 4):

I think I'd challenge your assumption of insufficient air traffic capacity.  You could equally well look at it as too many planes wanting to land, or (for NYC at least) insufficient passenger rail service.

Beyond that, have you looked at land prices in the vicinity of NYC or London?  Perhaps in some countries you can just seize land to build airports, over the objections of the people living there.  In the US (and presumably the UK, though I'm not certain), it's much more difficult to obtain, and should properly involve paying a fair market price - after long and expensive legal battles.

Then you have to consider trip duration.  It's not just time spent flying, but time getting to and from the airport.  In NYC, it's IIRC about a 15 minute bus ride from LaGuardia to Manhattan, and I think not much more from JFK.  Put the airport way out in the country, and people would spend an hour or two just getting there, negating the speed advantage of air travel for short & medium length flights.

Comment: Two closer airport is good for local but big troubles for connectors,and legal battles existed for airport expansion too---and you have to pay more fair value. I prefer a concentrated huge internatiobal hub, no matter expansion or new built, because it provides better experiences for connectors and also for airlines.

Comment: PS: Gatwick is located in sururban area and thames hub is in rural area. Personally I prefer 4runways (not 3) in hwathrow, but heathrow is surrounded by residential housing

Comment: @Him: But you are presumably not one of the people living on or near the proposed airport, or paying for it, so your preferences don't carry that much weight.

Answer (score 2):

Due to regulations, 2 runways in an airport are not answering less demand in an airport than 2 times one runway. So there is a loss of efficiency when 2 runways are built, that depends strongly of their relative orientation and their separation.

That means, that creating such a big airport will start requesting a massive size of land to have enough separation between airplanes and/or inefficient use of runways. You can easily finalize having flights of 1 hours and trips around that airport of 30 minutes.

Due to this limitation, and the potential cost of the land (usually very expensive close to the city) eliminates economies of scale, making more economically efficient to create 2 airports than creating a single big one.

Finally is a balance between several economical factors, but you can see that London, Paris, Berlin and New York are currently served by several airports.

Taking that information to answer your questions:

- Actually London is not thinking in creating a big airport, they are trying to expand [LHR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expansion_of_London_Heathrow_Airport) or [Gatwick](http://www.gatwickobviously.com/)
- Concerning NY, creating a big airport to replace La Guardia, Newark and JFK will be a very big airport very far from the city center and very likely to not be efficient.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying in your first paragraph. You have a good point though. Lots of large cities are served by multiple airports, for both historic and economic reasons.

Comment: @fooot, sorry for that. What I am trying to mean is that depending on how the runways are positioned relatively they will be allowed different modes of operations which create restrictions to use simultaneously the runways (or you move them away during the construction). So the capacity (number of flights) of a 2 runways is not the double of one runway isolated. Modes of operation are here: http://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/Parallel_Runway_Operation

Comment: @Trebia Project. At least mega airport was one opinion discussed by the airport commission in UK, even though it is rejected. But there is no such discussion in NY.

Comment: @Trebia Project Moreover several large cities including Mexico city , Istanbul and Beijing are building new mega airport instead of expansion.

Comment: In addition to the reasons listed above, they would be creating the world's new busiest airport.

Comment: @Him Mexico and Istanbul airports are planned for 6 runawys, that's not a "megairport".  O'hara in Chicago has got 7 runways and has another airport (Midway). Beijing (if the full project is constructured) will have 9 runways, which can be described as a megairport. That's right. In this case probably the economical criteria is not the main criteria. Probably prestige of having the biggest airport will be part of the decision although not economically as efficient as 2 airports (Maglev in Shangai is a similar example of prestige over economy)

Comment: @TrebiaProject. "mega" airport is more likely to be determined by size but not number of runways. Mexico city is half larger than Ohare and Istanbul is double size compared to Dallas.

Comment: @Him how you measure size? Notice that passengers, size of the terminal and runways are not independent parameters.

Comment: @trebia They are independent but runway capacity is much more than you expected, two closed parallel runways like dubai can serve more than 400k aircraft movement annual. Therefore 6 runways is enough to serve 3 major airport in ny. If the runway is widely seperated each runway can serve more flight, the london thames hub airport which serve 100k passengers, have 4 runways and 33km2 size only